# Contact form scrolls user to the middle of the page on load?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, scroll

This is a very strange issue but for some reason my contact form is causing my website to automatically scroll to the MIDDLE of the page. I have no idea why it's doing this... All I know is that when I delete the contact form code it loads normally, but I need this form for my site (this is what I get for semi-custom code lol)

Any thoughts and solutions? This is driving me nuts. :c

Here is my code for the contact form. Also if you guys know of any better ways to code what I got here (which im sure someone will point out) I will greatly appreciate it. :P

```
<div class="contact-form">
                <!--Form on submit checks if the user used more than 5 words, thanks to the onsubmit function-->
                <form method="post" action="process.php" onsubmit="var text = document.getElementById('message').value; if ($(this).find('textarea').val().match(/[a-z]+/gi).length < 5) { alert('Your Holler is too short. Try adding more words (min 5 words per message)'); return false; } return true;" >  
        <label for="name"><p>Name: <span class="required">*</span></p></label>  
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="John Doe" required autofocus />  

        <label for="email"><p>Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></p></label>  
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required />  

        <label for="telephone"><p>Telephone: </p></label>  
        <input type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="" />  

        <label for="enquiry"><p>Inquiry: </p></label>  
        <select id="enquiry" name="enquiry">  
            <option value="general">Freelance</option>  
            <option value="sales">Job Offering</option>  
            <option value="support">Requesting Resume</option> 
            <option value="support">Other</option> 
        </select>  

        <label for="message"><p>Message: <span class="required">*</span></p></label>  
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message must be 5 words or more" required data-minlength="5"></textarea>  
        <input type="submit" id="submit" action="process.php" OnSubmit="window.open('', 'foo', 'width=450,height=300,status=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes')" value="Send My Holler!" class="submit-button" />
        <p id="req-field-desc"><span class="required" style="color:#04B6DC;">*</span> indicates a required field</p>  
    </form>  

            </div> <!-- end contact-form -->
```

Comment: So far I tried removing all the javascript with no avail. But EUREKA! For some strange reason, I found this little bugger in my input code: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="John Doe" required autofocus />  The AUTOFOCUS attribute. When I deleted this, the site loaded at the top again. WOO! But Im wondering, would this effect my contact form in any way?

Comment: Yeap, autofocus is the culprit, it makes it so the browser will scroll automatically to where that focused element is. And no taking autofocus out will not harm anything it will just make the user have to manually click on the input to start entering something. I will delete my comments to clean up, and you can put that as an answer so that other users that come by this will know how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks so much Patrick! I will do the same, as well as to remove my site link XD Big thank you for such speedy responses and will give credit in pointing me in the right direction for this issue. You rock!

Comment: @XavierTheGreat Please post the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted instead of having it on the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EUREKA! Thanks to Patrick Evans I was able to know where to look and found the solution!

For some strange reason, I found this little bugger in my input code: The AUTOFOCUS attribute. When I deleted this, the site loaded at the top again. WOO!

So for anyone who is having a similar issue, check to make sure that your contact form does NOT have the autofocus attribute anywhere in the code.

Cheers!